# How to refactor/extract functionality from setup() into reusable function

Tags: javascript, typescript, variable-assignment, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I want to extract a function from an existing Vue 3 component, into a composable function usable in multiple components.

In my vue component, I use a function, which sets the ref-variable `reset` to `true` or `false` (triggered by a click).

## Current Solution:

The function to change the reset variable is in the setup function. Works fine.

### Component

```
// Vue3Component.vue
<script lang="ts">
import { ref, defineComponent } from "vue";
    export default defineComponent({

        setup() {
            const reset = ref(false);

          // Triggered by click
            function updatePaginatedPage(paginaValue: {
              resetState: boolean;
            }) {
                  // Sets reset to true or false
                  reset.value = paginaValue.resetState;
              }
            }
        }
    })
</script>
```

Since I need that functionality in another Vue component, I want to place the function in a hook file.

## Desired Solution:

The function to change the reset variable imported from a file into the setup function. I do not know, how I can assign the value to a variable (and more things in useUpdatePaginatedPage()) to assign the new value to the reset variable in the component.

### Component:

```
// Vue3Component.vue
<script lang="ts">
    import { ref, defineComponent } from "vue";
    import { useUpdatePaginatedPage } from "@/hooks/updatePaginatedPage";

    export default defineComponent({
        const reset = ref(false);

        // function from hook (below)
        useUpdatePaginatedPage({ resetState: false });

    })
</script>
```

### Hook / composeable function

```
// updatePaginatedPage.ts
export const useUpdatePaginatedPage = function(paginaValue: {
    currentPage: number;
    resetState: boolean;
  }, reset: any) {
    reset.value = paginaValue.resetState;
}
```

I do not know how to handle that.
I. e., how **reassign** `reset.value` from updatePaginatedPage.
I can pass it as argument, but what then?
Should I return the value and by another function in the component, assign it?

Comment: Yeah, I see that now. I hope it is now more readable and clear.

Answer (score 1):

1st I think your current solution is missing `return { reset, updatePaginatedPage }` (to make those values/functions available in template)

If you take a look at the `setup()` the `reset` variable is a local variable to the function. To make it reusable, you need again make it a local variable to some function - let's say `usePagination` - every time you call that function from the `setup()` of some component, new local `reset` variable and `updatePaginatedPage` bound to that variable will be created...

In some sense, the refactoring you need is just to take whole `setup()` function, rename it to something else and store it in it's own file...

Let's take a look at the code:

```js
// composables/usePagination.js
export usePagination(/* pass any params you want for desired behaviour */) {
  const reset = ref(false);

  function updatePaginatedPage(paginaValue: {
    resetState: boolean;
  }) {
    reset.value = paginaValue.resetState;
  }

  return { reset, updatePaginatedPage }
}
```

Then use it in some component...

```js
setup() {
  const { reset, updatePaginatedPage } = usePagination(/* pass any params you want for desired behaviour */)

  // make it available to component's template
  return { reset, updatePaginatedPage }
}
```

Comment: Hi Michal, Thank you at first for a better description of my problem.

The function works so far without returning anything. Just reassigning value to reset work quite well, if the function is in the component.

Thing is, at another time I need to reassign "reset" via another function.
That's why, I do not put reset in "usePagination" ...

What would be a better approach, to change a shared variable from different function/files. To use vuex seems to me overkill.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. So you don't want the `reset` to be a "per component" but instead somehow global state across multiple components or whole app?

Comment: No. reset stays in this componenent. Just the reassignment happens from functions outside of this component/file. The reset value can be changed from two different functions (both outside).

Comment: Sorry but it is too vague explanation. Maybe you can just make both functions part of the `usePagination` closure? I don't know. Anyway what I presented here is the way most composition functions i'v seen are structured - packing both the data and functionality together....